# No option to select existing Azure yaml file in one of our Azure DevOps projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When creating a new Pipeline in Azure DevOps projects, for one of our Azure projects, I don't get the option to select an existing yaml file. I've compared settings with our different projects but I don't understand why the wizard jumps straight past the Configure option without ability to go back.

Specifically, after creating "New pipeline"->"Azure Repos Git"->"Select a repository" the wizard jumps straight past the Configure option to Review tab. At this point I only get the option to review my YAML file (and rename the file - no option to pick branch or existing file).

[image]

The configure screen options I'm expecting but don't get:

[image]

Any ideas why this would only be happening for certain Azure DevOps projects/repos??

*Note: I have an existing yaml pipeline already in this Git repo (so do the other projects) - but even for the first pipeline I had to stuff around creating/editing/saving this file based on the default "starter pipeline" yaml file.*

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any official fix but this worked to me without having to remove any .yml files from any branch.

The URL that appears in the "Review" step looks like this:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{ORGANIZATION}/{PROJECT}/_apps/hub/ms.vss-build-web.ci-designer-hub?
sourceProvider=tfsgit&
telemetrySession={SESSION_ID}&
repositoryId={REPOSITORY_ID}&
repositoryName={REPOSITORY_NAME}&
branch={BRANCH_NAME}&
repositoryUrl={REPOSITORY_URL}&
sourceProviderComplete=true
```

**Workaround:** Replace branch name with a branch that has the .yml file you are looking for.

In my case ADO was putting 'Main' by default, and it didn't work until I changed it to 'Dev' which automatically redirected me to the 'Configure' tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had an "azure-pipelines.yml" file in my repository root folder/all branches. It seems that once I removed this from all branches the configure option worked as expected.

Comment: This is not working to me after I removed the file from one branch only.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Go through all the way to the end where it adds the default azure-pipelines.yml

Step 2: Click on the ellipse and click settings

[image]

Step 3: Specify the relative path to the azure-pipelines.yml in your directory, for example `/MySolutionFolder/ProjectDir/azure-pipelines.yml`. Note it might not exist in the drop-down, that's fine. Click save and it should appear.

[image]